# how to insert data type Json into mongodb by mongoose and use for?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, for-loop, mongoose

I try to insert google sheet Json file into MongoDb By mongoose and express.
But I used 'for' because to repeat insert data.
However, it does not enter the database.
this is my code.
response is look like

[image]

But If i run this file to nodejs
It is stored in the DB in this wrong form.

[image]

This is my Javasciprt code to insert MongoDb by Mongoose

```
 const response = (await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get(request)).data
  .values;
console.log(response.length);

for (let i = 1; i <= response.length; i++) {
  const jsonDatas = await Json.create(
    {
      name: response[i][0],
      start: response[i][1],
      desc: response[i][2],
      url: response[i][3],
    },
    function (err, small) {
      if (err) return hadleError(err);
    }
  );
  console.log(response);
  return jsonDatas;
}
```

This is my Schema type

```
const JsonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, require: true },
  start: { type: String },
  desc: { type: String },
  url: { type: String },
});
```

Help me pls

Comment: `i <= response.length` to `i < response.length`, and remove `function (err, small) {...`

Comment: Changing does not change the result.